# Param at ui-sref not passed

Tags: angularjs

I have my ui-sref code here.

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="vendor in Items" 
         id="scrollArea">
        <img src='{{vendor.img}}' 
             style='width:100%;' 
             ui-sref='vendordetail({vendorId:1})'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my $stateProvider

```
.state('vendordetail',{
     views:{
         url:'/:vendorId',
         'mycontainer':{
             templateUrl:'vendordetail',
             controller:function($scope, $stateParams) {
                 console.log('vendordetail controller');
                 console.log($stateParams);
             }
          }    
     }
});
```

The templateUrl "vendordetail" is displayed on the targeted ui-view "mycontainer" successfully. "vendor detail controller" string is logged as well. But the $stateParams is an empty object {}. What did I actually missed out to pass the param vendorId to my state controller?

I hope I am not missing out any context. Thanks in advance.